# LCD/OLED Historical Resolution, Size and Prices

Tags: historical, prices, technology

We are looking for historical data on the resolution, size and prices of LCD and OLED displays (consumer or business).

We are able to find current prices and also historical prices. Ideally, we would like to see the price per centimeter at a given resolution going back to the birth of each technology.